# How to debug evicted pod on k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubelet

I have searched some but could not get much as I am new to k8s. My pods are evicted and I get message as:

```
"Status:        Failed
Reason:         Evicted
Message:        The node was low on resource: nodefs."
```

Any help how can I figure out what is going on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Run `kubectl describe pod <pod name>` and look for the node name of this pod. Followed by `kubectl describe node <node-name>` that will show what type of resource cap the node is hitting under `Conditions:` section.

From my experience this happens when the host node runs out of disk space.

Comment: They look ok.
Conditions:
  Type             Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
  ----             ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------                       -------
  OutOfDisk        False   Mon, 26 Nov 2018 11:49:32 -0800   Mon, 05 Nov 2018 16:09:45 -0800   KubeletHasSufficientDisk     kubelet has sufficient disk space available

Comment: but you suggestion did help me get to cause. Thanks!. however not sure what else could I do to find the reason? will it be just to delete pods now as last resort?

Comment: It's hard to say then. You can try starting the pod again and monitor the describe command `watch kubectl describe node <>` and see if the condition values change. Also after starting the pod you should run `kubectl logs <pod-name> -f` and see if there are anything helpful on the log output.